# Differentiation of the euclidean norm of $\Vert Ax+b\Vert^{2}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ real matrix, $x$ an $n\times 1$ vector and $b$ an $m\times 1$ vector. I want to compute
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x} \Vert Ax+b\Vert^{2}.
\end{equation}
First, I expanded
\begin{equation}
\Vert Ax+b\Vert^{2}=(Ax+b)^{T}(Ax+b)=x^{T}A^{T}Ax+2x^{T}A^{T}b+b^{T}b
\end{equation}
then I computed
\begin{eqnarray}
\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}(x^{T}A^{T}Ax+2x^{T}A^{T}b+b^{T}b)=A^{T}Ax+x^{T}A^{T}A+2A^{T}b
\end{eqnarray}
but I know the above is wrong since $A^{T}Ax$ and $x^{T}A^{T}A$ does not have the same dimention. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than expanding *first*, do the opposite.  Define a new vector $$y=Ax+b$$ and write the function in terms of this new variable and the Frobenius product (which I'll denote by a colon). This approach reduces the visual "clutter". You can then expand the results *after* finding the derivative.

With the Frobenius product, finding the gradient is easy and fool-proof 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \|y\|^2 = y:y \cr
\cr
df &= 2\,y:dy \cr
  &= 2\,y:A\,dx \cr
  &= 2\,A^Ty:dx\cr
\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 2\,A^Ty \cr
  &= 2\,A^T(Ax+b) \cr
\cr
}$$
The rules for rearranging the Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
 A:B &= B:A \cr
 A:BC &= B^TA:C = AC^T:B\cr
}$$
can be derived from the familiar properties of the trace, since 
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$

Comment: This is not the first time I see someone suggesting calculating the derivative in terms of the Frobenius product, but I couldn't find any textbooks that would detail that approach.

Is there any chance you can point me to a good source?

Comment: Haha, I just realized it might be you who recommended that approach in other discussions.. I am not sure if you're aware, but there're people collecting your answers :)

https://gist.github.com/yig/c1959ce997f1d2fd6f3f982cb482e060

Answer (score 0):

A general way of finding the gradient $\nabla_x f(x)$ of any vector-valued function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is by using Taylor's Theorem, which can be expressed as such:
$$f(x+\delta) = f(x) + [\nabla_x f(x)]^\intercal \delta + o(||\delta||_2),$$
where $\delta\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is small.

For your example, let $f(x) := ||Ax+b||_2^2$. Applying Taylor's Theorem (above), 
we have that:
\begin{align}
f(x + \delta) &= ||A(x+\delta)+b||_2^2 \\
&= ||Ax+b + A\delta||_2^2\\
&= ||Ax + b||_2^2 + 2(Ax+b)^\intercal A\delta + ||A\delta||_2^2\\
&= f(x) + [2A^\intercal(Ax+b)]^\intercal \delta + o(||\delta||_2)\\
&= f(x) + [\nabla_x f(x)]^\intercal \delta + o(||\delta||_2).
\end{align}

Thus, the gradient $\nabla_x f(x)=2A^\intercal(Ax+b)$.

(The third line in the equations above is given by the equality
$||U+V||_2^2 = ||U||_2^2 + 2U^\intercal V + ||V||_2^2$, for any vectors $U, V \in \mathbb{R}^n$.)

Answer (score 0):

I was also interested in this and I found some useful information from the matrixcookbook. Note in your case $b = -q$.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(x) &= ||Ax-q||^2 \\
&= (Ax-q)^T(Ax-q) \\
&= (x^TA^T-q^T)(Ax-q) \\
&= x^TA^TAx - x^TA^Tq - q^TAx + q^Tq \\
&= x^TA^TAx - q^TAx - q^TAx + q^Tq \\
&= x^TA^TAx - 2q^TAx + q^Tq \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Now differentiate $f(x)$ with respect to $x$. To do this, make use of the formula: $\frac{d}{dx}(x^THx + c^Tx) = (H+H^T)x+c$.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{df}{dx} &= \frac{d}{dx}(x^TA^TAx) + \frac{d}{dx}(-2q^TAx) + \frac{d}{dx}(q^Tq) \\
&= ((A^TA)+(A^TA)^T)x + (-2q^TA)^T + 0 \\
&= 2A^TAx - 2A^Tq \\
&= 2A^T(Ax - q) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Since we used $b = -q$, then the answer becomes $\frac{df}{dx} = 2A^T(Ax+b)$