# Derivative of ||Ax-b||^2 and other derivatives of matrix expressions

Tags: optimization, vector-spaces, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I am currently taking Optimization Theory and the book I'm using has almost no examples and there aren't any answers to the exercise questions.  It's been a while since I worked with matrices and am even having difficulty searching for similar problems.

The question is as follows: Calculate ${f_x(x)}$ and ${f_{xx}(x)}$ for the following ${f(x)}$:

i.) ${f(x) = ({a^T}x)({b^T}x),}$ with ${ a,b\in {\mathbb{R}^n}}$

ii.) ${f(x)} = {x^T}Ax,$ with $A \in {\mathbb{S}^n}$. What happens if $A \in {\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}}$ is not symmetric?

iii.) ${f(x)} = {{\| Ax-b \|}^2},$ with $A \in {\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}}$ and $b \in {\mathbb{R}^m}$

iv.) ${f(x)}={sin({a^T}x)},$ with $a \in {\mathbb{R}^n}$

Unfortunately, I am having a hard time remembering how to work with stuff like this, so any help is greatly appreciated.  I did find this: [Differentiation of the euclidean norm of $\Vert Ax+b\Vert^{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2151937/differentiation-of-the-euclidean-norm-of-vert-axb-vert2)  but still don't rally know what's going on.

My work so far is as follows:

By simply following the power rule, I got

i.) ${f_{x}(x)}= 2{a^T}{b^T}x$

${f_{xx}(x)}= 2{a^T}{b^T}$

And for ii.)  ${f_x(x)}=d({x^T})Ax + {x^T}d(x) = {(dx)^T}Ax + {x^T}A(dx) = {(dx)^T}Ax + {(dx)^T}{A^T}x = {(dx)^T}(A+{A^T}x)$

But again, I am not confident in what I am doing.  And, now I'm stuck on (iii.).  Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your answer for (i) is not correct; it should be $ab^T+ba^T$. I think if the book doesn't give you the shortcut rules for calculating vector derivatives, you may be expected to derive everything yourself from first principles at this point. For example, the derivative of $(a^Tx)(b^Tx)$ is the vector whose $i$th component is $\partial((a^Tx)(b^Tx))/\partial x_i$; expand this using the product rule and see what you get. In the end, try to express the result as a vector again.

Comment: Then again, it's easier to work with differentials: The gradient of a function $f(x)$ is the vector $g$ such that $f(x+\delta x) = f(x) + g\cdot\delta x$ for infinitesimal $\delta x$. So you can plug in $x+\delta x$ into your function, expand, ignore higher powers of $\delta x$, and get the result into the above form; that'll give you the derivative.

Comment: Answer (ii) for non-symmetric $A$ and you'll have an answer for 3 questions. Setting $A=ab^T$ gives you the answer to (i). And noting that $A+A^T=2A$ when $A$ is symmetric gives you the answer to the first part of (ii).  There are lots of posts on this site which address question (iii). For question (iv) note that $u=a^Tx$ is an ordinary (scalar) variable, so elementary calculus tells you that $df=\cos(u)\,du$.