# Derivative of $(Ax)^T Ax$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, vectors

This derivative comes up in the differentiation of the euclidean norm and I can't seem to find an appropriate rule to apply that the dimensions match. I know the solution is:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left((A x)^{\top} A  x\right)=2  A^{\top} A x $$

I tried applying the product rule and swapping the transpose with the derivative:

\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left((A x)^{\top} A  x\right) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( (Ax)^{\top} \right) Ax  + (Ax)^{\top} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( Ax \right) \\&= A^{\top} Ax  + (Ax)^{\top} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( Ax \right)
\end{align}

The left term seems to be correct but the right term is bothering me because the dimensions don't match.

I'm looking for some rule that I can apply and remember in case I ever see a similar derivative. I looked through the Matrix Cookbook and googled but couldn't find anything.

I also came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2151937/differentiation-of-the-euclidean-norm-of-vert-axb-vert2) but the answers didn't really explain it to my satisfaction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly does $\partial / \partial x$ mean here, gradient?

Comment: @PeterFranek derivative with respect to the vector x

Comment: The product rule (as you've written it) is only valid when $x$ is a scalar. It is not valid when $x$ is a vector or a matrix! You must take into account the fact that the Jacobian $\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)$ is a matrix, and matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Comment: @greg are you sure that this product rule isn't correct? It is stated in the Matrix Cookbook Equation 33 (https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.867/wiki/images/7/77/Matrix_cookbook.pdf)

Comment: @Seen Equation 33 applies to the _differential_ (not the gradient) of a product. The differential of a vector $(dy)$ is a vector quantity, but the gradient of a vector $\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)$ is a matrix.

Comment: @greg Ok I see. So in general my misconception (and why my derivation here doesn't work) is that there aren't as accessible rules in Matrix calculus as they are in the scalar case? So I'd need to think about it in a sum notation or more general about the Jacobian?

Comment: @Seen In general, you should think about problems in terms of _differentials_.  See the latter chapters of _Matrix Differential Calculus_ by Magnus and Neudecker.

Comment: I'll have a look at it, thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to work componentwise with [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation):$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(Ax)_j(Ax)_j=2(Ax)_j\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(A_{jk}x_k)=2(Ax)_jA_{ji}=2(A^TAx)_i,$$so the gradient is $2A^TAx$.

Comment: Thank you, it helped understand why the derivative is correct. However I was more hoping for some general rule so that I don't have to write the product in sum notation.

Comment: @Seen Any such general rules would be proven with this notation. For example, once you note$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}u_jv_j=\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}v_j+u_j\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i},\,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(Ax)_j=A_{ji},$$you can restate these as$$\nabla_x(u^Tv)=(\nabla_xu)v+(\nabla_xv)u,\,\nabla_x(Ax)=A^T.$$These two rules can be used to solve your original problem,as well as others like it.

Comment: great! So I guess I mishandled the transpose and need to study the derivatives more